# CSS styles from style tag not properly being applied to page

Tags: html, css

Trying to generate a pdf with jsPDF from an html page, I was successful at this but for some reason my styles were not being applied to Firefox, I started looking into the html that was being generated and I see that when I open the HTML as is locally the styles are not applied for some reason, this should be quite simple all the styles are in the style tag and I am not importing a file yet no go. here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>FF Testing</title>
    <style>
      html {
        box-sizing: border-box !important;
      }

      .page_added {
        border: 0 none !important;
      }
      .body_sub {
        font-size: 1rem !important;
        font-family: Aria, sans-serif;
        font-size: 1rem;
        font-weight: 400;
        line-height: 1.5;
        color: #212529;
        background-color: #fff !important;
        margin: 0 !important;
        padding: 1rem !important;
        box-sizing: border-box !important;
      }
      table {
        width: 100% !important;
        /*margin-bottom: 1rem;*/
        background-color: transparent !important;
        /*border-collapse: separate !important;*/
        /*border-spacing: 0 !important;*/
        padding: 0 !important;
        margin: 0 !important;
      }
      tr {
        padding-bottom: 0;
        padding-top: 0;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        margin-top: 0;
        border-spacing: 0;
        border: 1px solid #dee2e6;
        background-color: transparent;
        /*border-collapse: collapse;*/
      }
      .title {
        border: 0 none !important;
      }
      .table td {
        padding: 8px;
        vertical-align: top;
      }
      .table td.or {
        font-weight: bold;
        color: blue;
        background: #dee2e6;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 1.5rem;
      }
      .and {
        font-weight: bold;
        color: blue;
      }
      .table td.origin {
        font-weight: bold;
        color: black;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 1.5rem;
        /*break-before: avoid;*/
      }
      .diseeaseTitle {
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 1.5rem;
        padding-bottom: 8px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="body_sub">
      <table class="table">
        <tr class="title">
          <td colspan="3">
            <h2>NBA5387430702 <br /></h2>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="title">
          <td colspan="3">
            <small
              >Subtitle here Subtitle here Subtitle here Subtitle here Subtitle here Subtitle here Subtitle here</small
            >
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="title">
          <td colspan="3">
            <h3 class="diseeaseTitle">
              <strong>TITLE TITLE TITLE TITLE TITLE </strong>
            </h3>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3" class="origin"> Smaller title Smaller title Smaller title</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="1" style="width: 40%;">question number one?</td>
          <td colspan="1">
            Year
          </td>
          <td colspan="1"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="1" style="width: 40%;">
            questions number two which is slightly longer not as short as question one?
          </td>
          <td colspan="1">
            Single Choice
          </td>
          <td colspan="1">
            <span>
              Some answer option; </span
            ><span>
              No; </span
            ><span>
              Not sure; </span
            ><span>
              Another answer option (AAO);
            </span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="1" style="width: 40%;">
            This is also a question since this is a questionnaire so I need many questions, ok?
          </td>
          <td colspan="1">
            Single Choice
          </td>
          <td colspan="1">
            <span>
              Below 30 percent; </span
            ><span>
              30-39 percent; </span
            ><span>
              40-49 percent; </span
            ><span>
              50-59 percent; </span
            ><span>
              60-69 percent; </span
            ><span>
              70-90 percent; </span
            ><span>
              80 percent of greater; </span
            ><span>
              Not sure; </span
            ><span>
              Last Option
            </span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="1" style="width: 40%;">
            Are you currently reading this questionnaire right now, crazy stuff huh?
          </td>
          <td colspan="1">
            Multiple Choice
          </td>
          <td colspan="1">
            <span>
              Answer 3534; </span
            ><span>
              Some other answer; </span
            ><span>
              Bla bLa bal; </span
            ><span>
              Zebras giraffes and thingamiaggers; </span
            ><span>
              ghslhgslikh; </span
            ><span>
              skljgslkn; </span
            ><span>
              xngbxklbgl; </span
            ><span>
              svgmsmn; </span
            ><span>
              hsxshfshsd; </span
            ><span>
              xhdxhsdh; </span
            ><span>
              Not sure; </span
            ><span>
              Not taking this anymore
            </span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="1" style="width: 40%;">
            Do you have any of the following something something ? Please select all that apply.
          </td>
          <td colspan="1">
            Multiple Choice
          </td>
          <td colspan="1">
            <span>
              this that or possibly those things; </span
            ><span>
              Active boromoter (chronic or acute); </span
            ><span>
              Active craziness requires treatment; </span
            ><span>
              Chronic eating of burgers; </span
            ><span>
              Serious addicition to football; </span
            ><span>
              No significant conditions
            </span>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>

      <!---->
      <table class="table">
        <!---->
      </table>
      <p style="break-before: page;">
        &nbsp;
      </p>
      <table class="table">
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3" class="origin">
            Match Criteria for this questionnaire
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="width: 40%;">What year were you born?</td>
          <td>is greater than (years)</td>
          <td></td>
          <td><!----></td>
        </tr>
        <!---->
      </table>

      <p style="break-before: page;">&nbsp;</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

It looks terrible some of the issues are that the borders in the `tr` elemnents do not show, but more generally that it seems that at least most of the styles are not being applied. What am I missing that my styles are not being applied?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your styles and it should work

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

most of the styles wont be applied to `tr`.

you will have to give your style for border to `td`. For removing the spaces between `td` syou have to add attributes `cellspacing=0` and `cellpadding=0` to the `table`. You can add `border-top` and `border-bottom` for every `td`s and `border-left` for `first-child` and `border-right` for `last-child`.

hope you get it

Answer (score 1):

1. First of all there is no class called as **.or** and **.and** so the styles cannot be applied.
2. You have misspelled the **padding-bottom** property in tr style.
3. To get the border to the table you need to add **border-collapse: collapse;** property in your table style.

I have made some changes to your code and all are working fine according to me, Let me know if you want to add some more styles or the changes need to be done in the code.

Code :-

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>FF Testing</title>
    <style>
      html {
        box-sizing: border-box !important;
      }

      .page_added {
        border: 0 none !important;
      }
      .body_sub {
        font-size: 1rem !important;
        font-family: Aria, sans-serif;
        font-size: 1rem;
        font-weight: 400;
        line-height: 1.5;
        color: #212529;
        background-color: #fff !important;
        margin: 0 !important;
        padding: 1rem !important;
        box-sizing: border-box !important;
      }
      table {
        width: 100% !important;
        /*margin-bottom: 1rem;*/
        background-color: transparent !important;
        /*border-collapse: separate !important;*/
        /*border-spacing: 0 !important;*/
        padding: 0 !important;
        margin: 0 !important;
        border-collapse:collapse; 
      }
      tr {
        padding-bottom: 0;
        padding-top: 0;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        margin-top: 0;
        border-spacing: 0;
        border: 1px solid #dee2e6;
        background-color: transparent;
        /*border-collapse: collapse;*/
      }
      
      .title {
        border: 0 none !important;
      }
       
      td {
        padding: 8px;
        vertical-align: top;
      }
      
       .origin {
        font-weight: bold;
        color: blue;
        background: #dee2e6;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 1.5rem;
      }
      
      .origin {
        font-weight: bold;
        color: black;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 1.5rem;
        /*break-before: avoid;*/
      }
      .diseeaseTitle {
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 1.5rem;
        padding-bottom: 8px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="body_sub">
      <table class="table">
        <tr class="title">
          <td colspan="3">
            <h2>NBA5387430702 <br /></h2>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="title">
          <td colspan="3">
            <small
              >Subtitle here Subtitle here Subtitle here Subtitle here Subtitle here Subtitle here Subtitle here</small
            >
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="title">
          <td colspan="3">
            <h3 class="diseeaseTitle">
              <strong>TITLE TITLE TITLE TITLE TITLE </strong>
            </h3>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3" class="origin"> Smaller title Smaller title Smaller title</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="1" style="width: 40%;">question number one?</td>
          <td colspan="1">
            Year
          </td>
          <td colspan="1"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="1" style="width: 40%;">
            questions number two which is slightly longer not as short as question one?
          </td>
          <td colspan="1">
            Single Choice
          </td>
          <td colspan="1">
            <span>
              Some answer option; </span
            ><span>
              No; </span
            ><span>
              Not sure; </span
            ><span>
              Another answer option (AAO);
            </span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="1" style="width: 40%;">
            This is also a question since this is a questionnaire so I need many questions, ok?
          </td>
          <td colspan="1">
            Single Choice
          </td>
          <td colspan="1">
            <span>
              Below 30 percent; </span
            ><span>
              30-39 percent; </span
            ><span>
              40-49 percent; </span
            ><span>
              50-59 percent; </span
            ><span>
              60-69 percent; </span
            ><span>
              70-90 percent; </span
            ><span>
              80 percent of greater; </span
            ><span>
              Not sure; </span
            ><span>
              Last Option
            </span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="1" style="width: 40%;">
            Are you currently reading this questionnaire right now, crazy stuff huh?
          </td>
          <td colspan="1">
            Multiple Choice
          </td>
          <td colspan="1">
            <span>
              Answer 3534; </span
            ><span>
              Some other answer; </span
            ><span>
              Bla bLa bal; </span
            ><span>
              Zebras giraffes and thingamiaggers; </span
            ><span>
              ghslhgslikh; </span
            ><span>
              skljgslkn; </span
            ><span>
              xngbxklbgl; </span
            ><span>
              svgmsmn; </span
            ><span>
              hsxshfshsd; </span
            ><span>
              xhdxhsdh; </span
            ><span>
              Not sure; </span
            ><span>
              Not taking this anymore
            </span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="1" style="width: 40%;">
            Do you have any of the following something something ? Please select all that apply.
          </td>
          <td colspan="1">
            Multiple Choice
          </td>
          <td colspan="1">
            <span>
              this that or possibly those things; </span
            ><span>
              Active boromoter (chronic or acute); </span
            ><span>
              Active craziness requires treatment; </span
            ><span>
              Chronic eating of burgers; </span
            ><span>
              Serious addicition to football; </span
            ><span>
              No significant conditions
            </span>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>

      <!---->
      <table class="table">
        <!---->
      </table>
      <p style="break-before: page;">
        &nbsp;
      </p>
      <table class="table">
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3" class="origin">
            Match Criteria for this questionnaire
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="width: 40%;">What year were you born?</td>
          <td>is greater than (years)</td>
          <td></td>
          <td><!----></td>
        </tr>
        <!---->
      </table>

      <p style="break-before: page;">&nbsp;</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```